# jqgrid - How to show edit form, when click on row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I need to show an edit form when clicking on a row or when clicking on my custom button.
I can get the id of the row which was clicked, but how do I show the form and edit this row?

Answer (score 2):

Use `jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid, properties );`

For more detail see [JQGrid Form Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing)

Answer (score -1):

Normally i will use a dialog to show the form. Here is the sample code, see whether meet your requirement or not

```
$('#button').click(function () {
            showDialog("Your URL ",'TITLE', 400, 320);
        });



    function showDialog(url, title, iwidth, iheight) {

var dialog = $('<div id="divpopup"><iframe id="iframedit" src="' + url + '" style="width:' + iwidth + 'px;height:' + iheight + 'px;"  frameborder="0" ></iframe></div>').appendTo('body');
//dialog.remove();
dialog.dialog({
    title: title,
    autoResize: true,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    modal: true,
    position: 'center',
    draggable: true,
    open: function (type, data) { },
    close: function (type, data) { }
})
);
}
```

Comment: does not provide any clue for solving the problem